# Programming Rock, Paper, Scissors choice combinations - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Forgive me if a topic on this has already been created, but I've looked and can't seem to find it.

I am trying to figure out how get an output of every single possible combination of rock paper scissors choices there are based on X amount games.

The equation for how many possible results there are is simple - X^Y = Results.

(X to the Yth power--where X equals the number of games and Y equals the number of choices--equals the number of possible combinations.)

So lets say one person plays three games of rock, paper, scissors. That's `3^3 = 27`.

If `rock = 1`, `scissors = 2`, and `paper = 3`, ( I listed them in this order so it can go from left to right on which beats which) then the results would be:
111,
112,
113,
121,
122,
123
... and so on...

But the question is, how do I get this to output? 
For 3^3, I could just do an outer loop, with 1 inner loop, then 1 inner loop for that one. 
But I need it to be dynamic, so that I can pass in X for the number of games, and Y for the number of choices, and have it return an array of all the possible combinations of choices there are. So I'm thinking that I can have 1 loop for every column (where columns equal the number of games) .. I'm just not sure how I'd do this.

I need the results to be in an array so I can look for certain combos later on.

Can anyone help me out with this?

All I really need is the logic, so pseudo-code would be fine. But a solid script would be great too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this library solves your problem: https://github.com/dankogai/js-combinatorics (script: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dankogai/js-combinatorics/master/combinatorics.js)
The function you would use is:

```
baseN = Combinatorics.baseN([1,2,3], 3);
console.log(baseN.toArray())
```

Where 1,2,3 are the possible options and 3 is the number of repetitions. This will give an array of the 27 different combinations you can achieve.

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
     combine(a,a);

function combine(srcArr, oldArr)    {
    var newArr = [];
    while(oldArr[0].length < srcArr.length)
    for(i=0; i<srcArr.length; i++)  {
    for(j=0; j<oldArr.length; j++)  {
        newArr.push(oldArr[j] + srcArr[i]); 
    }
    }
        combine(srcArr, newArr);
    } 
}
```

This is a recursive algorithm that is initiated by the starting array and an identical seed array. On each function call, a new array is created by adding each member of the starting array to each member of the seed array. The new array becomes the seed array for the next function call. You can see the recursion in action by inserting the code line `alert(newArr);` on a line before the if

Comment: What does this do? Adding an explanation of why this is an answer might help.

Comment: it's a recursive algorithm that is initiated by the starting array and an identical seed array. On each function call, a new array is created by adding each member of the starting array to each member of the seed array.  The new array becomes the seed array for the next function call.  You can see the recursion in action by inserting the code line <code>alert(newArr);</code> on a line before the <code>if</code) statement.  There's a more elegant way to exit with the returned result, which I'll post if you're interested

Comment: You should add the explanation to the answer.